# Do I get a bonus d6 to Magic Missile damage if my expert sidekick helps me?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, sidekick

[The expert sidekick has the *helpful* ability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dc/sidekicks#Expert) (at level 7+):

> The expert can take the Help action as a bonus action, and the creature who receives the help gains a 1d6 bonus to the d20 roll. If that roll is an attack roll, the creature can forgo adding the bonus to it, and then if the attack hits, the creature can add the bonus to the attack’s damage roll against one target.

Since [Magic Missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile) automatically hits and is ruled over the years that [one must throw only 1d4 and apply that same roll to each dart](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/how-many-times-do-you-roll-damage-for-magic-missile), does the damage for each dart then become 1d4 + 1 + 1d6?

Comment: Incredibly related: "[How does the Evocation wizard's Empowered Evocation feature work with the Magic Missile spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47140)"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No.

*Magic missile* doesn't involve any d20 roll (attack or otherwise), so there's no roll for the Helpful feature to modify in any way.

Answer (score 18):

The *Magic Missile* spell does not require an attack, so it the benefits of the sidekick's *helpful* ability would not apply. Similarly, you couldn't apply the extra damage to other spells that are not attacks, like *Burning Hands* or *Fireball*. But since the ability doesn't specify weapon attacks only, it would apply to spell attacks, like those from *Eldritch Blast* or *Melf's Acid Arrow*.